# Table cells resizing when browser resizes

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```css
table td
{
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Everything is fine if the browser is big enough. But if I resize my browser and make it too small, my cells resize. How can I make them stay a fixed width?

Here it is in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y2wHn/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this to your CSS:

```
table td
{
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

This specifies a minimum-width, so it can never be smaller than 300px.

amosrivera's suggestion is also a good way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed width on the table:

```
table {
    width: 900px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set width of the whole table not td

```
table{width:900px;}
table td
    {    border:1px solid black;

    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y2wHn/6/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the table to a specified width as well, otherwise it will resize based on the browsers window size.

Updated code:

```
table { width: 900px; }
table td
    {
        width: 300px;
        background-color: #432152;
    }
```

Comment: Hehe seems like 4 ppl answered at the same time... :)

Answer (score 0):

what about if u add a current css rule:

```
table {
  width: 900px;
}
```

fixed table width no?